# Who enforces MPAA rating adherence?

Tags: content-rating

Let's say one opens a new movie theater in New York City that is accessible to the public. Are there any laws in New York state or the US in general that would force the cinema to adhere to MPAA ratings and age-restrict access to certain showings? Or is it all completely voluntary and there are in fact cinemas that don't care about the MPAA?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## It's voluntary.

Here's a little bit of an interview with a representative from the National Association of Theatre Owners (NATO):

> “The rating system is voluntary, but we strongly encourage theaters to enforce the rating age restrictions as applied to any movie,” a NATO spokesperson told theWrap.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[MPAA Can’t Enforce Rating as NY Theater Ignores NC-17 for ‘Blue Is the Warmest Color’ - TheWrap](https://www.thewrap.com/mpaa-helpess-enforce-ratings-ny-theater-ignores-nc-17-blue-warmest-color/)</sub>

So, yes it is completely voluntary. In the same article, an example is provided of a theatre that ignored the rating provided by the MPAA.

> One major New York theater, the IFC Center, has announced that it will not enforce the NC-17 rating given to “Blue Is the Warmest Color” — and there is nothing the Motion Picture Association of America can do to make them do it.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[MPAA Can’t Enforce Rating as NY Theater Ignores NC-17 for ‘Blue Is the Warmest Color’ - TheWrap](https://www.thewrap.com/mpaa-helpess-enforce-ratings-ny-theater-ignores-nc-17-blue-warmest-color/)</sub>

So, theatres completely have the right to ignore the MPAA.

Comment: Do the studios (who I think are members of the MPAA, right?) have any way to prohibit distribution to theaters that don't comply?

Comment: The voluntary rating system exists to pre-empt a forced rating system, so there is incentive for the movie industry to at least appear to “enforce” it, so that public outrage doesn’t grow to the point that laws are passed (or studios are boycotted).

Comment: @user1118321 Studios could prohibit distribution to theaters that don't comply; they aren't required to distribute their movie to any theater. However, they make money at every theater they distribute to, and they might make _more_ money at theaters that don't enforce age restrictions, so studios probably ignore whether theaters comply or not.

Comment: For the reason @ToddWilcox mentions, the studios probably don't completely ignore compliance failures. As long as it's rare they probably won't do much, but if it becomes too widespread (and we can only guess what that would be in practice, I don't think a movie theatre in a major city like NYC probably could get away with doing it consistently) they will probably act.

Comment: What does NATO stand for?

Comment: @Acccumulation National Association of Theater Owners. Answer should definitely clarify that.

Comment: @yoozer8: yeah, the only NATO I've heard of is the North Atlantic Treaty Organization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO), so I wondered what the military was had to do with this (for half a second until I realized it must be something else I'd never heard of.)  Anyway, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Association_of_Theatre_Owners

Comment: If a single theater chose to disregard the rating of a movie, I expect the backlash from outraged parents (or whoever) would *mostly* be focused on that theater.  Only local people would really be affected, after all.  The MPAA would, of course, publicly denounce the theater's choice on social media, but might not otherwise take any action or stop selling them movies.  I wouldn't really expect any kind of "enforcement" unless a reasonably sized *chain of theaters* chose to disregard the ratings system, to the point where it became more than a "local problem."

Comment: Trump is planning to leave NATO anyway....

Comment: @PeterCordes - Hey, we've all have to pick up work where we can when times are slow

Comment: @ToddWilcox: There *were* laws. They [were overturned by the Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Burstyn,_Inc._v._Wilson), and since then, the Court has become notably *more* protective of free speech, so it's quite unlikely that any new laws would ever survive legal scrutiny. We've seen the same fight play out over [video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_v._Entertainment_Merchants_Ass%27n), for example, with the same result. The ratings are nothing more than marketing "lanes" (i.e. "little kids' movies in the G lane, older kids in PG, etc.").